# Dataframe error: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: python, pandas

I find the way how to drop rows with a condition, but it doesn't work. Please suggest another solution or say why it doesn't work

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на Stack Overflow вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего `data_mean` и `data_std` у вас получились не скалярами, а `Series` с лейблами, соответствующими колонкам `dataset`. Таким образом, нужно у `upper` и `lower` взять соответствующий столбцу элемент:

```
dataset = dataset[dataset['price'] >= upper['price']]
dataset = dataset[dataset['price'] <= lower['price']]
```

Но, кроме того, вы неправильно делаете выборку, мне кажется, при таком подходе у вас останется пустой `dataset`. Правильно будет, наверное, так (тем более, что условия можно совместить через булевый оператор `и`):

```
dataset = dataset[(dataset['price'] >= lower['price']) & (dataset['price'] <= upper['price'])]
```